# HowTo copy Text from TextFlow

Tags: javafx

I have a `VBox`, inside multiple `TextFlow`s. How can I make this Text selectable/ copyable?

```
public class ExampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private VBox box;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final URL location, final ResourceBundle resources) {
    final TextFlow tf = new TextFlow();
    final Text t0 = new Text("First part");
    final Text t1 = new Text(", second");      
    final Text t2 = new Text(" and third");
    t0.getStyleClass().add("first-part-styling");
    t1.getStyleClass().add("second-part-styling");
    t2.getStyleClass().add("third-part-styling");
    tf.getChildren().addAll(t0, t1, t2);
    this.box.getChildren().add(tf);
    }
}
```

I use `TextFlow` and `Text`, since I need different styling within the same sentence.

Comment: You could include [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) in your project. I guess it will cover most of your needs out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, using `Text`, as this class is supposed to only display text. But you can use `TextField`instead:

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        final TextFlow tf = new TextFlow();
        final Text t0 = new Text("First part");
        final Text t1 = new Text(", second");
        final TextField t2 = new TextField(" and third");
        t2.setEditable(false);
        t2.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
        t2.setFocusTraversable(false);

        tf.getChildren().addAll(t0, t1, t2);
        root.getChildren().add(tf);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: third text is not selected]
[image: third text is selected]

*Edit* You might take a look at
[Rich-text area for JavaFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX). This open source project on GitHub provides a styleable text area. Have not tried it, though...

Comment: What if the string is very long? E.g. final TextField t2 = new TextField(" and very, very, very long third"); Furthermore, the spacing between "second" and "and third" is not the same as the other one. I guess TextField would need some additional styling.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, if you solely rely on TextField, the differing spacing would be no problem. In fact, I would suggest using only one TextField and put all your text there. Or do you need to have them as separate ui objects? If your text spans more than one line, you might use TextArea instead.

Comment: I see. I have edited my answer to include a link to Rich-text area for JavaFX, an open source project on GitHub... Have not tried it, though...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   ObservableList<Node> nodesTextFlow = box.getChildren();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Node node : nodesTextFlow) {

            ObservableList<Node> nodesText = ((TextFlow) node).getChildren();
            for (Node node1 : nodesText) {
                sb.append((((Text) node1).getText()));
            }
    }
   String txt = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This does not provide the possibility for separate styling of the different `Text` elements.